# Link to a specific tab for jquery tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

http://jsfiddle.net/78QPs/

This is the Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".tab_content").hide();
$(".tab_content:first").show(); 

$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(".tab_content").hide();
    var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
    $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn(); 
});
```

});

I have used the above to make my tabs but I want to link to tabs2 & tab3 in my above example from another webpage using a href. Any other way other than using Jquery UI like javascript?

In short, How do I create a link to a tab directly from another page and within the page from the above example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that is 1) Listen for the Hash, and 2) trigger the click of the relevant 'tab'.

---

Now Im not 100% on the support for this event listener from jquery - but I'll add it it.

```
   /* listen for the anchor hashtag change */
    $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
     /* trigger the click of the tab with the matching rel */
     var _rel =  document.location.hash.
      $("li[rel="+_rel.substring(1)+"]").click();
     });
```

---

Or use this listener of sorts which is native, ( I use it but I might need to update to the above if it works out ).

```
var _currhash;

 function anchorWatch() {
  if(document.location.hash.length>0) {
    /* only run if 'hash' has changed */
     if(_currhash!==document.location.hash) {
       _currhash = document.location.hash;

          $("li[rel="+ _currhash.substring(1)+"]").click();

     }
   }
 } 
 setInterval(anchorWatch,300);
```

---

Here is a demo and code of something I added on another q that could be relevant : -  **http://jsbin.com/soqopepe/1/edit**

*( not using jquery tabs), but works in the same way *

---

Here is a demo of your code with this added :

http://jsfiddle.net/sa2Lj/

To try, http://jsfiddle.net/sa2Lj/show/#tab3

Comment: you mean if the url was like `somepage.php`? Yes, then would be like this `somepage.php#tab4` to show tab4 for example

Comment: Thanks. it worked right. But when I clik the link from outside, it scrolls down to the tab part. But I have a fixed banner at top at 104px, so the tabs are get behind it when the page is loaded causing me to scroll down. Is there any way to avoid the scroll?

Comment: Hi @PoochiTeap, understand. When the hash matches an element on the page, the default browser behaviour is to jump to it. Change either the hash or  the id on the 'tabs' - eg if the id was `<div id="showtab1">` and the hash link was `page.php#tab1` the line to trigger the click could be `$("li[rel=show"+ _currhash.substring(1)+"]").click();` - now the hash does not match an id on the page - hope makes sense , rushing here , but will check back later.

Answer (score 0):

You have various options: use a hash inside your url to reference the id of your tab, and retrieve it with window.location.hash.

So let's say you have a tab with id='tab' and window.location.hash = 'tab', you can do $(window.location.hash).hide().

Another good option would be using the HTML5 history function to change the URL accordingly to the tab selected. This would also be more much nicer, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

for the most cross-browser compatible solution ty something like this:

```
var queryString = {};
window.location.href.replace(
new RegExp("([^?=&]+)(=([^&]*))?", "g"),
function($0, $1, $2, $3) { queryString[$1] = $3; }
);

if (queryString[base.options.param]) {

var tab = $("a[href='#" + queryString[base.options.param] + "']");

tab
    .closest(".tab_content")
    .find("a")
    .removeClass("active")
    .end()
    .next(".list-wrap")
    .find("ul")
    .hide();
tab.addClass("current");
$("#" + queryString[base.options.param]).show();

};
```

this assigns each tab a query string parameter value.

Comment: can you implement this into my fiddle with the link posted here?.. I cant seem to figure it out

Comment: Sure thing. I'll do it write now.