# How to highlight selected tab in tabbed navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery

How in this example can I set the highlight of the selected tab?

And how can I set the first tab to be active when the page is opened, if none is set?

```js
    var $tabs = $('.tabs > div'), _currhash, $currTab;
    
    function showTab() {
       if($currTab.length>0) {  
         $tabs.removeClass('active');
         $currTab.addClass('active');
       }
    }
    $tabs.each(function() {
       var _id = $(this).attr('id');
       $(this).attr('id',_id+'_tab');
    });

    function anchorWatch() {
      if(document.location.hash.length>0) {
        if(_currhash!==document.location.hash) {
           _currhash = document.location.hash;
           $currTab = $(_currhash+'_tab');
           showTab();
       }
      }
    } 
    setInterval(anchorWatch,300);
```

```css
.tabs > div { display:none;}
.tabs > div.active { display:block;}

a { display:inline-block; padding:0.5em;}
.tabs > div { padding:1em; border:2px solid #ccc;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#tab1">tab1</a>
<a href="#tab2">tab2</a>
<a href="#tab3">tab3</a>

<div class="tabs">
  <div id="tab1">content one</div>
  <div id="tab2">content two</div>
  <div id="tab3">content three</div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mnqzasf8/)**

Comment: Please add your code in your question , If external link expires the question will become invalid

Comment: Why you used `setInterval` for click on each `hash` ?

Comment: @ametyst why did you use jquery tab ?

Comment: you need to learn it more. Because your approach is not good. please lern tabs more

Comment: @ametyst tabs with CSS and JavaScript. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp

Comment: @Pedram I was inspired here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23793895/link-to-a-specific-tab-for-jquery-tabs

Comment: @ManuVarghese I'm doing a project, administration interface. I have a menu on the left and a navigation menu with tabs on the top right that will always open the part I need.

Comment: @ametyst already an inbuilt jquery tab is available. then why should you do build a new one from plain js and CSS. I strongly suggest this  https://jqueryui.com/tabs/